# phpmyadmin: Automatically open a specific table once logged in

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I would like to simplify the task of opening a table when logging in to phpMyAdmin.  What I would like to happen, is instead of a user logging in, selecting a database, then selecting a table - is there a way to modify it so the user logs in and the database and table are already selected?

I ask this because on my setup, there is only 1 database, and 1 table.  If there is a way to login and simplify the task of accessing the table , that would be amazing.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Then why waste your time working out how to do it automatically. When you create your second table, or second database you wont want to do this!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767395/phpmyadmin-default-to-structure-instead-of-browse